# Retrieve data from multiple different Azure Tables asynchronously with Azure Tables client library

Tags: python, azure, asynchronous, python-asyncio, azure-table-storage

Is it possible with the [Azure Tables client library for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/data-tables-readme?view=azure-python) to retrieve data from multiple tables asynchronously? Let's say I have table A and B in different storage accounts, is it possible to retrieve data from both tabels simultaneously levering the `asyncio` module?

I cannot find any documentation specifying whether this is possible or how to implement this. I can think of building two async functions that can retrieve data from the tables and calling them via `asyncio.gather()`. Would this work or can the actual outbound call to the Azure endpoint not be done asynchronously?

I see that there exists a
[Azure Data Tables aio](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-data-tables/12.0.0b6/azure.data.tables.aio.html) module which might be leveraged for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

You can use the below code to retrieve the data for two tables in different storage accounts using **`asyncio method`**.

**Code:**

```
import asyncio
from azure.data.tables.aio import TableServiceClient

async def retrieve_table_data1(table_name):
    async with TableServiceClient.from_connection_string("<connect_string1>") as table_service:
        async with table_service.get_table_client(table_name) as table_client:
            async for entity in table_client.list_entities():
                print(entity)

async def retrieve_table_data2(table_name):
    async with TableServiceClient.from_connection_string("<connect_string2>") as table_service:
        async with table_service.get_table_client(table_name) as table_client:
            async for entity in table_client.list_entities():
                print(entity)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        retrieve_table_data1("table1"),
        retrieve_table_data2("table2"),
    )
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
asyncio.run(main())
```

**Console:**

The above code executed successfully and retrieved data from two tables.

[image]